# Are exceptions from RPCs the same as normal exceptions?

Tags: distributed-computing

Trying to understand more about RPCs to answer a homework question: Are exceptions handle the same way for the caller? Are the details of how exceptions are raised on the server any different? Are there any additional differences if you have to rethrow?

OR, can someone just explain what the main differences are between local and remote exceptions? And maybe give an idea of what things to look out for if I wanted to implement remote exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version of an RPC server / client library:

```
Server:
  try
    receive message
    deserialize arguments
    invoke appropriate method
    serialize result
    transmit result
  catch any Exeption
    serialize Exception
    transmit Exception


Client (Library code, not the caller):
  try
    serialize arguments
    make remote call
    receive "something"
    deserialize "something" (could be serialized exception or result)
  catch Timeout,Network,Other exceptions not from server
    handle whatever the library handles
  if deserialized "something" is an exception
    rethrow exception from server for caller to catch
  else, good/expected results
    return results
```

So, if you want exceptions to be caught by the caller, they possibly differ from regular exceptions in that they must be serialized and transmitted over the network to be re-thrown for the caller.

The caller need not do anything special if the Client library exists. If the client library doesn't exist, then the caller needs to also take the role of the client library. This means that the caller needs to distinguish between serialized results and serialized exceptions (at which point the programmer would probably implement an ad-hoc version of the client library code anyway just to avoid having ugly caller code).

Obviously you can't just use type signatures to distinguish between Exceptions and results (otherwise, what happens if the return type and the exception types for an RPC method were the same?). So there's a tiny bit of overhead in the serialization code for the server to label the different responses.